# Index number clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to show the index of a bunch of clicked links in a UL.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Slide 3</a></li>
</ul>

$(".menu li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    slideIndex = $(this).index();
    console.log(slideIndex);

});
```

Now in console it just shows 0, what have I missed here?  I want it to show 1 or 2 if I click the other 2 links.  I guess this is probably elementary but I am a little unsure.

Comment: *return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object **relative to its sibling** elements.* `$(this)` has no siblings in your example.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to:

```
$(".menu li").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    slideIndex = $(this).index();
    console.log(slideIndex);

});
```

Otherwise you are checking index of `a` in `li`, which is always 0, as there is only one `a` in every `li`.

Answer (score 2):

you should reach your `<li>` element index like

```
$(".menu li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    slideIndex = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log(slideIndex);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-ind='1'>Slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-ind='2'>Slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-ind='3'>Slide 3</a></li>
</ul>

$(".menu li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var slideIndex = $(this).data('ind');
    console.log(slideIndex);

});
```